# when does onCreateOptionsMenu get called when activity is in tab?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-tabhost, actionbarsherlock

I have a tabHost and adding activity to the tab.

> Intent myIntent = new Intent(this, MyActivity.class);
>   mySpec.setContent(myIntent);

but MyActivity's onCreateOptionsMenu doesn't get called.

How do I add item to actionBar when my activity is in a tab?

I want to add different items to actionBar in different tabs(activities)

Answer (score 0):

Since the introduction of the ActionBar the tab API has changed a lot. Tabhosts are now deprecated Tabs inside a Tabhost will not affect the actionbar.

I would recommend to completely abandon TabHosts and use the [ActionBarSherlock](http://actionbarsherlock.com/) to get a native ActionBar on Devices beyond Android 3.2

In this way you get better looking tabs on all devices and the menu is correctly displayed on Phones with Android 4.x

Comment: I find tabhost much easier to use because of the abundant tutorials and S.O. answers. Even ActionBarSherlock example source code(tab related) uses tab host inside them. I thought tab host is still fine to use.